# Extract text between dynamic HTML tags using python soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a requirement where i need to extract the text between HTML tags. I used BeautifulSoup to extract data and store the text into a variable for further processing. Later i found that, the text which i need to extract is coming in two different tags. However please note that i need to extract the text and store into same variable. My earlier code and sample HTML text information is provided. Please help me how to get my end results i.e expected output.

Sample HTML text:

```
<DIV CLASS="c0"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">1 of 80 DOCUMENTS</SPAN></P>
<DIV CLASS="c0"><BR><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Financial Times (London, England)</SPAN></P>
<DIV CLASS="c0"><BR><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Copyright 2015 The Financial Times Ltd.<BR>All Rights Reserved<BR>Please do not cut and paste FT articles and redistribute by email or post to the web.</SPAN></P>

<DIV CLASS="c0"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">80 of 80 DOCUMENTS</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<BR><DIV CLASS="c3"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Financial Times (London,England)</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
<DIV CLASS="c3"><P CLASS="c1"><SPAN CLASS="c2">Copyright 1990 The Financial Times Limited</SPAN></P>
</DIV>
```

From the above HTML text, i need to store documents(1 of 80 documents, 80 of 80 documents) into a single variable. similarly for other text it follows similar approach. I wrote code for div.c0

```
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
        docpublicationcpyright = soup.select('div.c0')

        list1 = [b.text.strip() for b in docpublicationcpyright]
        doccountvalues = list1[0:len(list1):3]
        publicationvalues = list1[1:len(list1):3]
        copyrightvalues = list1[2:len(list1):3]
        documentcount = doccountvalues

        publicationpaper = publicationvalues
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could anyone help me out with this

Comment: post the output sample you want.

Comment: Sample Output: documentcount=[1 of 80 DOCUMENTS,80 of 80 DOCUMENTS],publicationpaper =[Financial Times (London, England),Financial Times (London, England)]

Comment: this html code is not consistent, i do not have solution.

Comment: Can anyone else help me out with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Any help on the above issue

Comment: Is there is anyone to help me on the above issue. I do not have any clue to proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given sample HTML is not properly structured. For example: closing tag is missing for first DIV element. Anyways for this type of HTML also using **regular expressions** you can scrape required data.

I wrote a sample code considering only sample HTML posted in the question & able to extract the all three required fields

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')

documentElements = soup.find_all('span', text=re.compile(r'of [0-9]+ DOCUMENTS'))
documentCountList = []
publicationPaperList = []
documentPublicationCopyrightList = []
for elem in documentElements:
    documentCountList.append(elem.get_text().strip())
    if elem.parent.find_next_sibling('div'):
        publicationPaperList.append(elem.parent.find_next_sibling('div').find('span').get_text().strip())
        documentPublicationCopyrightList.append(elem.parent.find_next_sibling('div').find_all('span')[1].get_text())
    else:
        publicationPaperList.append(elem.parent.parent.find_next('div').get_text().strip())
        documentPublicationCopyrightList.append(elem.parent.parent.find_next('div').find_next('div').get_text().strip())

print(documentCountList)
print(publicationPaperList)
print(documentPublicationCopyrightList)
```

output looks like below

```
[u'1 of 80 DOCUMENTS', u'80 of 80 DOCUMENTS']
[u'Financial Times (London, England)', u'Financial Times (London,England)']
[u'Copyright 2015 The Financial Times Ltd.All Rights ReservedPlease do not cut and paste FT articles and redistribute by email or post to the web.', u'Copyright 1990 The Financial Times Limited']
```